# Convert from char array to 16bit signed int and 32bit unsigned int

Tags: c, types, embedded, string-conversion

I'm working on some embedded C for a PCB I've developed, but my C is a little rusty!

I'm looking to do some conversions from a char array to various integer types.

First Example:

```
[input]        " 1234" (note the space before the 1)
[convert to]   (int16_t) 1234
```

Second Example:

```
[input]        "-1234"
[convert to]   (int16_t) -1234
```

Third Example:

```
[input]        "2017061234"
[convert to]   (uint32_t) 2017061234
```

I've tried playing around with atoi(), but I don't seem to be getting the result I expected. Any suggestions?

[EDIT]

This is the code for the conversions:

```
char *c_sensor_id = "0061176056";
char *c_reading1 = " 3630";
char *c_reading2 = "-24.30";

uint32_t sensor_id = atoi(c_sensor_id); // comes out as 536880136
uint16_t reading1 = atoi(c_reading1); // comes out as 9224
uint16_t reading2 = atoi(c_reading2); // comes out as 9224
```

Comment: This is not quite there yet in terms of spec. What is the list of possible integral types, and the order in which they should be applied?

Comment: What does "playing around" mean? What did you get and what did you expect? You should show your code involved.

Comment: Apologies - wrote this in a frustrated rush! :) I've added the code and the outputs I got.

Comment: In the cases of the readings, you say you want to convert them to `int16_t`, but in your code you use a `uint16_t` type.

Comment: How exactly does `uint16_t reading2  = .... "-24.30"` make sense to you?

Comment: The observed behavior is inconsistent with the code fragments you posted. Please post a complete program along with its output so we can determine what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

- Never use the `atoi` family of functions since they have no error handling and may crash if the input format is bad. Instead, use the `strtol` family of functions.
- Either of these functions is somewhat resource heavy on resource-constrained microcontrollers. You might have to roll out your own version of `strtol`.

Example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main() 
{
  const char* c_sensor_id = "0061176056";
  const char* c_reading1  = " 3630";
  const char* c_reading2  = "-1234";

  c_reading1++; // fix the weird string format

  uint32_t sensor_id = (uint32_t)strtoul(c_sensor_id, NULL, 10);
  uint16_t reading1  = (uint16_t)strtoul(c_reading1,  NULL, 10);
  int16_t  reading2  = (int16_t) strtol (c_reading2,  NULL, 10);

  printf("%"PRIu32 "\n", sensor_id);
  printf("%"PRIu16 "\n", reading1);
  printf("%"PRId16 "\n", reading2);

}
```

Output:

```
61176056
3630
-1234
```

Answer (score 1):

The observed behavior is very surprising.  I suggest writing functions to convert character strings to `int32_t` and `uint32_t` and use them instead of `atoi()`:

```
uint32_t atou32(const char *s) {
    uint32_t v = 0;
    while (*s == ' ')
        s++;
    while (*s >= '0' && *s <= '9')
        v = v * 10 + *s++ - '0';
    return v;
}

int32_t atos32(const char *s) {
    while (*s == ' ')
        s++;
    return (*s == '-') ? -atou32(s + 1) : atou32(s);
}
```

There is no error handling, a `+` is not even supported but at least the value is converted as 32 bits, which would not be the case for `atoi()` if type `int` only has 16 bits on your target platform.

Answer (score -2):

Try initializing your strings like this:

```
char c_sensor_id[] = "0061176056";
char c_reading1[] = " 3630";
char c_reading2[] = "-24.30";
```

Comment: Care to elaborate?